# How to open different domain or sub domain to new tab and same domain link to same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

I need a way to get the link open in new tab if the link belongs to the different hostname or different sub domain. There is possibility that same site can be hosted with different domain or sub domain. 
 I don't have control over the html, as this is taken by some sort of bot, which I need to handle it. 
Ex1. **page request URL : example.com** 
have links:

```
<a href="//app.example.com">app example</a> 
<a href="//www.info.example.com">info example</a>
<a href="https://example.com/abc">example abc</a>
<a href="https://www.example2.com">example2</a>
```

I need it to resolve like

```
<a href="//app.example.com" target="_blank">app example</a> 
<a href="//info.example.com" target="_blank">info example</a>
<a href="https://example.com/abc" target="_self">example abc</a>
<a href="https://www.example2.com" target="_blank">example2</a>
```

---

Ex2. **page request URL: info.example.com** 
have links:

```
<a href="//app.example.com">app example</a> 
<a href="//www.info.example.com">info example</a>
<a href="http://tst.example.com/abc">example abc</a>
<a href="https//dev.example2.com">example2</a>
```

I need it to resolve like

```
<a href="//app.example.com" target="_blank">app example</a> 
<a href="//wwww.info.example.com" target="_self">info abc</a>
<a href="http://tst.example.com/abc" target="_blank">example abc</a>
<a href="https//dev.example2.com" target="_blank">example2</a>
```

I tried this as well
[Open all external links open in a new tab apart from a domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071254/open-all-external-links-open-in-a-new-tab-apart-from-a-domain)

but it does not work with the subdomain.

Comment: Can you share your updated js code?  The question in the link provided does the opposite (but should work in your scenario) and the answer does something very different.

Comment: Hi, @freedomn-m I have updated my question it should clarify more now.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to compare to current page and make any other sub-domain or main domain open in other tab you can do:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.host !=== location.host
}).attr('target','_blank');
```

An `<a>` element has many similar properties to `location` and `host` is one of them

Comment: Was not aware that you could do `this.host` on an `<a>`.   Nice

Comment: Liking the filter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `endswith` instead of `===` when comparing host with the anchor's host.

However, as pointed out in the comments, your rules between Ex1 and Ex2 do not match:

- ex1 uses an exact match on the hostname, ignoring any path (eg google.com does *not* match info.google.com)
- ex2 uses a hostname match, ignoring anything on the left (eg info.google.com does match www.info.google.com)

The snippet below uses the rules from the second example

```js
var pagehost1 = "google.com"; // location.host;

$('.ex1 a').each(function(){
    if (this.host.endsWith(pagehost1)) {
        //$(this).attr('target','_blank');
        $(this).addClass("match");
    }
});

var pagehost2 = "info.google.com"; // location.host;

$('.ex2 a').each(function(){
    if (this.host.endsWith(pagehost2)) {
        //$(this).attr('target','_blank');
        $(this).addClass("match");
    }
});
```

```css
.match { color: green; }
a { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='ex1'>
<a href="//app.google.com">app google</a> 
<a href="//www.info.google.com">info google</a>
<a href="https://google.com/abc">google abc</a>
<a href="https://www.apple.com">apple</a>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class='ex2'>
<a href="//app.google.com">app google</a> 
<a href="//www.info.google.com">info google</a>
<a href="http://wwwtst.google.com/abc">google abc</a>
<a href="https//wwwdev.apple.com">apple</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

In this code ONLY google.com will get _self, anything.google.com and other sites will get _blank

That is including google.com:8080 if you are on google.com:80  -- so different ports also get _blank - if you wand different ports, same hose, then change to location.hostname

```js
let currentHost = "google.com"; // location.host; // change in the real page
$(function() {
  $("a").each(function() {
    this.target=this.host===currentHost?"self":"_blank";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://app.google.com">app google</a><br/>
<a href="https://info.google.com">info google</a> <br/>
**<a href="https://google.com/abc">google abc</a>**<br/>
<a href="https://google.com:8080">other google port</a><br/>
<a href="https://apple.com">apple</a><br/>
```

Comment: I guess this won't work in my case can you check again my question I've updated for more clarity @mplungjan

Comment: @UjjwalJha I do not understand your specification. Half of your hrefs are not valid and I do not see a pattern between example 1 and 2. Please explain the rules "Google has links" does not make sense

Comment: I have updated it now would you be able to understand it @mplungjan

Comment: Nope. I do not see any improvement in description of the issue. “Google has links” do s not make any sense to me

Comment: In a website, there is 3-4 subdomain and few external links, What I want whenever I am navigating through anchor tag It should open in the same tab if navigating URL is same else should open in new tab. I hope this would clear you more @mplungjan

Comment: @UjjwalJha Please see update - it was a lot simpler than the way you explained it if I have understood it right