# Open all external URL in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

My website have tons of internal and external URL.

for my hostname or `"#" href` it should open in same tab but for any other domain then my hostname should be open in new tab.

This code making all url open in new tab including internal links.

```
<base target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
```

Also tried (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12071371)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('a[href^="https://"],a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){

      // NEW - excluded domains list
      var excludes = [
         'google.com',
         'www.example.com',
         '*.example.com'
      ];
      for(i=0; i<excludes.length; i++) {
         if(this.href.indexOf(excludes[i]) != -1) {
            return true; // continue each() with next link
         }
      }

      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {

           // attach a do-nothing event handler to ensure we can 'trigger' a click on this link
           $(this).click(function() { return true; }); 

           $(this).attr({
               target: "_blank",
               rel: "noreferrer nofollow noopener",
               title: "Opens in a new window"
           });

           $(this).click(); // trigger it
      }
   })
     
});
```

Please provide the solution in HTML, javascript or PHP.

Comment: In addition to the `base` tag, use `target="_self"` on links that should override that. Or, if there are more links that should open in the current tab, don't use `base` at all and just add `target="_blank"` to the links that should be external.

Comment: @ScottMarcus there is tons of links and i cannot add `target="_self"` or `target="_blank"` for all of them

Comment: Create a JS that checks all `<a>`s href attribue. If it doesn't contain your domain name or is not `#`, add `target="_blank"` to the `<a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With javascript you can loop through all links and add `target="_blank"` to any links that don't match current domain:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e =>
{
  document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach(a =>
  {
    if (location.hostname == new URL(a.href).hostname)
      return;

    a.target = "_blank";
    a.rel = "noreferrer nofollow noopener";
  });
});
```

```css
.content
{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="/">internal link</a>
  <a href="#test">internal link 2</a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">external link</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">external link 2</a>
</div>
<div id="test" class="content">blah</div>
```

Comment: Code works!. How to add `noreferrer nofollow` for external link in this JS code?

Comment: edited the code

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over all the `a` elements and check to see if it's `href`  contains `http://` or `https://` and if so, set `target="_blank"` on the link:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(element){
  let href = element.getAttribute("href");
  
  // Check to see if the the href include http:// or https://
  if(href.includes("http://") || href.includes("https://")){
    element.target = "_blank"; // Make link open in new tab
    element.rel = "noreferrer nofollow noopener"; 
  }
  
  console.log(element); // Just for testing
});
```

```html
<a href="foo.html">Link</a><br>
<a href="http://foo.html">Link</a><br>
<a href="foo.html">Link</a><br>
<a href="https://foo.html">Link</a>
```

Comment: you can filter it directly in querySelector with `a[href^="https://"],a[href^="http://"]` and also don't need use getAttribute, since it can be accessed via `element.href` property, also this assumes that internal links are using relative paths

Comment: This code is not working :(. i am testing in my localhost. does it need real domain?

Comment: @ANUJSHARMA As you can see here, the code does work. You need to make sure you've added the script to the bottom of the HTML, just prior to the closing `body` tag so that by the time it's executed, all the HTML will have been parsed into memory. It doesn't matter if you are working on your own server or not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus now it working when i placed this code at bottom, before closing `body`. before i was using it in `head`. But totally confused. why this code do not work in head and work in end of HTML?

Comment: @ANUJSHARMA If the JavaScript is in the `head`, it will execute before the HTML parser has encountered any of the elements in the `body` and so, it won't find any `a` elements to work on. Including scripts just before the closing `body` allows for the script to run AFTER the HTML has been parsed into memory.

Comment: @ScottMarcus then how `@Vanowm` code works in `head` tag

Comment: @ANUJSHARMA Because that code is set to run when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is triggered, which is essentially at the same moment as when all the HTML has been parsed into memory. His code is "read", but waits to "execute". Moving your script to the end of the `body` is slightly more efficient because you aren't setting up any event handler.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Got it. Thank you for code and explain. :)